# Negative results occurs when calculate cross-track distance(distance between line segment and point on sphere)

Tags: java, android, math

I referred [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and calcualte the the distance between a line segment and a point on a sphere.I used cross-track distance formula as,

```
double distanceBetweenPointAndLineSegment = Math.asin(Math.sin(distance13 / earthRadius) * Math.sin(bearing13 - bearing12)) * earthRadius;
```

sometimes it results negative value.When negative values will occur? and how to take(or interpret)this distance?

Also I have seen along-track distance.What is the differnce between Cross-track distance and along-track distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can happen if the coordinates of (x,y) are in fact values under (x",y"). 
That doesn't mean that the value is negative, but that the **substraction is always made in the same order:**

```
(x-x"), (y-y").
```

So, the distance, negative or positive, will always mean the same. Two distances of -2 and + 2 between two points are mathematically identic.

The distance from A to B where `B(x,y)=(2,2)` and `A(x,y)= (1,1)` will be `AB(x,y)=(-1,-1)`. The distance from B to A will be `BA(x,y)=(1,1)`. But both points are equally distant.

In resume, you can **ignore** the signal, as it will only tell you the point of origin for the measurement.

Comment: But actaully the shortest between my line and point is around 60000 meters(60 KM). But I got answer as -150 using above formaula.So my doubt is cross-track distance is enough to find shortest distance between line segment and point on sphere,or need to calculate along side distance?

Comment: If your aim is to compute the distance of a point to a great-circle path, yes it's enough. As far as I see it.

Comment: I above formula i used earth radius as double earthRadius = 6371; shall i need to convert this from Km to Meter. I think distance returned is in meter.

Comment: You can convert that to meters, only if all the other measurements are in meters ; )

Comment: yes it is correct.I converted the earth radius to meters.Now I got correct result.